# Android Studio, fetch specific database row on login and diplay it list view

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an sqlite database that the user can register to! I have successfully created a login form and when the login is successful (username & password matchthe database's) the user is redirected to another activity. What i want is in the activity that the user is redirected, to diplay his entire database row (id,username, books,email,course, password, student name)!!in a list view or any other possible format Any ideas?? 
This the database creation code

```
static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "+"LOGIN"+
        "( " +"ID"+" integer primary key autoincrement,"+ "USERNAME  varchar2," +
        "PASSWORD varchar2, COURSE varchar2, EMAIL varchar2, STUDENT_NAME varchar2); ";
```

and this is the code that stores data in the database:

```
public void insertEntry(String userName,String password,String course,String email, String student_name)
{
    ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
    // Assign values for each row.
    newValues.put("USERNAME", userName);
    newValues.put("PASSWORD",password);
    newValues.put("COURSE", course);
    newValues.put("EMAIL",email);
    newValues.put("STUDENT_NAME", student_name);

    // Insert the row into your table
    db.insert("LOGIN", null, newValues);
    ///Toast.makeText(context, "Reminder Is Successfully Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Finally this ths login code

```
if(password.equals(storedPassword))
            {
                Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Congrats: Login Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                dialog.dismiss();
                startActivity(new Intent(MyActivity.this, Login_home.class));
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "User Name or Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

I would really appreciate if you could help me!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could create your custom class wherein you can store the fetched values from sqlite database using select query with members based on keyname.Considering your example i suspect user has only one row with different members you dont really need a listview you can rather add these values in texview and append it to a linear layout.Listview is used in incase if you have multiple users to display data.

A similar kind of example you need is in the link
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

It is a comprehensive lesson for beginner using sqlite

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! The problem is that i have no idea how to fetch an entire row from the database based on someone's id or username and display it in another activity!! I don't know how to make this class!!

Comment: @michalis See my edited answer. Also regarding the fetching you have put condition for username in your select query

Comment: The fact is that I don't know how to syntax a query that will match the value that was entered on the textbox in the previous activity in order to display the database row in the activity that the user is redirected!! For example select * from tablename where username equals what??